# Merge 2 Videos in one with command line (maybe Virtual Dub?)

Tags: c#, merge, video-editing

I have a C# program here which needs to merge 2 video files into one. First I tried around doing it in C# but I think it needs just to much time and knowledge to do so.

Now I'm searching for a program with command line params which can do this for me. I looked in the Virtual Dub docs but didnt find anything there.

Here is a screenshot of what I need to do:

http://public.slay.it/MARTIN-PC/634283051086584052.png

Video 2 needs to be like a overlay over video 1. Does anyone knows a program which can do this or maybe even a c# framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Avisynth](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Main_Page) with PIP see a [demo](http://www.hitthebongo.co.uk/wordpress/?p=20)

Comment: hehe that is what you're going to say when using Avisynth, btw use AvsP editor is really amazing

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of video files you're using, the exact codecs etc.
Without knowing the codecs involved it's hard to give an answer.
Your link won't work either so I might be wasting your time.

From my experience, both videos would need to have exactly the same specs in order to stitch them together to present one output. Otherwise you'll be re-encoding them and that might be way too slow for your application.

I also don't think VirtualDub or Avisynth are the right options here.

If your videos are mp4, MPEG-4, DivX, XviD, 3ivx etc you have a good chance of doing this really fast using mp4box. It's open source, command line and also Google use it :)